# Calculating median time between two times using strtotime

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the time between two values.

```
echo date("g:i a", (strtotime($moonrise) + strtotime($moonset))/2)
```

This is working well, however I am running into an issue if the moon sets the following day (EG 12.30am +1day).

Any suggestions as to how to solve this? I tried adding tomorrow / +1day but didnt seem to make a difference?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I tried adding tomorrow again and it worked! For others

```
date("g:i a", (strtotime($moonrise) + strtotime('tomorrow '.$moonset))/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about that ?

```
$start = date_create('2017-03-02 15:00:00');
$end = date_create('2017-03-02 18:15:00');
$diff=date_diff($end,$start);

echo $diff->format('%H:%i');
```